# "В этот день, я прошу у Вас прощенья" - нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

*В этот день, я прошу у Вас прощенья.*

Нужна ли запятая и почему?

Answer (score 4):

Запятая не нужна, потому что выражение "в этот день" – обычное обстоятельство, не требующее обособления, так как оно не является ни уточнением, ни деепричастным оборотом, ни одиночным деепричастием.

Answer (score 2):

***В этот день //я прошу у Вас прощенья.***

Запятая не ставится, хотя обстоятельство  ***в этот день*** выделяется небольшой паузой, так как  относится ко всему предложению. Но интонационная пауза не обозначается запятой.

Для обособления обстоятельства нужно грамматическое и смысловое **обоснование**. В данном случае обстоятельство времени не выделяется запятой, так как   стоит **в начале предложения, не имеет дополнительного значения уточнения, не является**  распространенным.

**Пояснение у Розенталя:**

Обособление обстоятельственных оборотов на основе существительных является **факультативным и зависит от ряда факторов.** 
Обособление оборота требуется объяснить: позиция в середине предложения, значительная распространенность, дополнительное уточняющее или второе обстоятельственное значение.

Подробнее: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114#pp114